# .addClass not working (gets removed on refresh)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm pretty new to jQuery and I'm trying to set a class based on `localStorage.getItem`but it isn't working. Here is my code:

```
if (localStorage.getItem("active_layout") == 2) {
   $("#laa").addClass("active");
};
```

The localstorage item has the value of 2 and the class gets added when I click on the element. But when I refresh, it gets removed. Is it possible to keep it there and not get removed on refresh?

Comment: When you refresh the page is reloaded from the server - you'll need to persist the information back to your server somehow, or re-add the class based on your local storage when the page loads.

Comment: As I said, I'm very new to jQuery. How can I re-add the class? Help is much appreciated :)

Comment: See below, I've added an answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try re-adding the class on document ready:

```
$(function() {
    if (localStorage.getItem("active_layout") == 2) {
       $("#laa").addClass("active");
    };
});
```

Comment: Accepted the answer, can't upvote as I don't have enough reputation *cries*

Answer (score 0):

add Active  Class as default and remove it when you not need ...

```
if (localStorage.getItem("active_layout") !== 2) {
   $("#laa").removeClass("active");
};
```

or add this Class Ready method

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if (localStorage.getItem("active_layout") == 2) {
       $("#laa").addClass("active");
    };
});
```

Comment: This will still be undone when the page is refreshed.

Comment: Tried @EvanKnowles answer and it removes the class `active` if the localStorage item isn't 2.

Comment: That's the alternate way but it better add class on ready function

Answer (score 0):

When the page is refreshed you will get a completely new page. Changes done with javascript will have to be redone.

If you want to use localstorage you will have to re-add the class on every refresh (Like Evan's answer).

You could also add some serverside logic so that the html is served with the class you want. However the server cannot read localstorage - you could use a cookie.